# Responsive CSS div positioning priority

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

first of all I would like to thank the members of this community for the huge amount of help I
found here in last few month. There wasn't a single project of mine which I finalized without your tips and tricks.

Right now I got a problem with a responsive layout where I need your kind help:

I got a layout like this:
http://codepen.io/Buzzjump/pen/tfeys

```
<div class='outer'>
<div class='sidebar_links'>Div1</div>
<div class='mitte_rechts'>
<div class='d2'>Div2</div>
<div class='d1'>Div3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now the current CSS

```
div{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#cdcdcd;
  margin:0px; 0;padding:0px;width:150px}
.d1{
    float:right;
    background: blue;
  color: white;
}
.d2{
  background: orange;
}
.mitte_rechts{
    padding:0;
    width:70.81%;
  float: left;
  margin-left:0px;
}

.sidebar_links{
    height: 200px;
    float: left;    
  background: red;
}

.outer{
    height: 230px;
  min-width: 80%;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

There is an outer box (outer) and two inner boxes (Div1 and mitte_rechts). In 'mitte_rechts' there are two more boxes(Div 2, Div3) and they are all aligned. What I want is that when the window is scaled down to a breakpoint (768) first Div3 is display under Div2 in mitte_rechts. Maybe I'm just blockheaded but is there a solution for this?
To this point no JS is used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following:

```
.d1 {
    float: right;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

.d2 {
    background: orange;
    float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .d1, .d2 {
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

By the way: You don't need `inline-block` on your divs. Inline-block is an alternative to floating. So either use floating or inline-block. I'm not a fan of inline-block because IE6 and IE7 don't support it.

Comment: Thanks bitWorking, your hints worked. I will implement it in my project today.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

1) remove `width:70.81%;' from '.mitte_rechts`

2) add the following styling:

```
 .d1, .d2{
   float:left;
 }

 @media (min-width: 768px){
   .mitte_rechts{
     width:70.81%;
   }

   .d1{
     float:right;
   }
 }
```