# How control <div> display order in responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have had lot of search on google and stackoverflow also but couldn't find a solution for this issuu.
My question is this that how can i control that when in browser reach to breakpoint the  with left float(`mainleft`) goes to down of  with right float(`mainright`)?
Thanks

This question on stackoverflow ir regarding the priority of div floating but cannot help me:
[Responsive CSS div positioning priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981280/responsive-css-div-positioning-priority)

You can see my issue in jsfidle in this address:

https://jsfiddle.net/jamshidi/8ahb03qn/1/

**Html:**

```
 <div class="maincontainer">
 <div class="mainleft">
 mainleft
 </div>
 <div class="mainright">
 mainright
 </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
 <div class="footer-end">
 footer
 </div>
 </footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .maincontainer{
 height:auto;
 width: 700px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden;  
 }
.mainleft{
float: left;
width: 200px;
height:auto;
background-color: #D0D1F9;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
 .mainright{
float: right;
width: 500px;
height:auto;
background-color: #C4F4D6;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
 .footer-end{
height:35px;
width: 700px;
background-color: #bb0700;
color:#fff;
padding-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
clear:both;
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.mainleft{
float: none;
width: 100%;
height:auto;
background-color: #D0D1F9;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
 .mainright{
float: none;
width: 100%;
height:auto;
background-color: #C4F4D6;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

there are at least 2 ways to do this. one with CSS and the other with JQ

**1. with CSS** : using `float:right` on both `divs` and rearrange the HTML structure ( `mainright` first and then `mainleft` )

```css
.maincontainer{
  height:auto;
 width: 700px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden;  
  }
    .mainleft{
 float: right;
 width: 200px;
 height:auto;
 background-color: #D0D1F9;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
  .mainright{
 float: right;
 width: 500px;
 height:auto;
 background-color: #C4F4D6;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
     .footer-end{
 height:35px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: #bb0700;
    color:#fff;
 padding-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 clear:both;
   }
      @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .mainleft{
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 background-color: #D0D1F9;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
  .mainright{
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 background-color: #C4F4D6;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontainer">
  <div class="mainright">
mainright
 </div>

  <div class="mainleft">
mainleft
  </div>
  
  </div>
   <footer>
  
   <div class="footer-end">
   footer
   </div>
   
 </footer>
```

or see fiddle > **[solution with CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/8ahb03qn/4/)**

*OR* also with CSS ,you can leave `float:left` on `mainleft` but change the structure as the above example.

**2. width JQ** ( if you can't change the html structure ) : when `$(window).width()` is smaller than `500px` , move `mainleft` after `mainright`

```js
$(window).on("resize",function(){
if($(window).width() < 500) {
   $('.mainleft').insertAfter('.mainright')
   }
})
```

```css
.maincontainer{
  height:auto;
 width: 700px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden;  
  }
    .mainleft{
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height:auto;
 background-color: #D0D1F9;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
  .mainright{
 float: right;
 width: 500px;
 height:auto;
 background-color: #C4F4D6;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
     .footer-end{
 height:35px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: #bb0700;
    color:#fff;
 padding-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 clear:both;
   }
      @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .mainleft{
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 background-color: #D0D1F9;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
  .mainright{
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 background-color: #C4F4D6;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maincontainer">
  <div class="mainleft">
mainleft
 </div>

  <div class="mainright">
mainright
  </div>
  
  </div>
   <footer>
  
   <div class="footer-end">
   footer
   </div>
   
 </footer>
```

or see fiddle > **[solution with JQ](https://jsfiddle.net/8ahb03qn/5/)**

Comment: Thanks,have you tested your codes?it doesn't work,the 'mainleft' go up when decrease browser size.

Comment: yes. they are tested. both of them.  with JQ you had to refresh the page after resizing to `<500px` , but i introduced a `resize` function so now it's more clear that it works

Comment: Thanks a lot,your first solution is very good for me,i never thought that it has this simple solution.  But i test the second solution on jfiddle and it doesn't work why?

Comment: did you test it now ? it works perfectly ( i changed a bit the code . added a resize function )

Comment: My mean is put your new link of jsfiddle after updating  on stackoverflow.

Comment: see here : https://jsfiddle.net/8ahb03qn/5/ it works ON RESIZE . so when you resize the window from something bigger than 500 to something smaller than 500 . if you want it to work on refresh of the page, ( that would be ideal for use on mobile phones ) , just delete the window resize function ( and the closing brackets `})` ) and when you get under 500px refresh page. that's how JQ works. because when you enter a website from a mobile phone, you don't resize a window, you enter directly on a specific screen size.

Comment: if you have more questions click the link : Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121332/discussion-between-mihai-t-and-kaveh).

Comment: glad i could help ! do not forget to rate my answer as accepted :) . thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this could be repositioning the divs above the breakpoint.
You could manage this with `float:left and float:right` while the HTML part is in hierarchically opposite.

[The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ahb03qn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that with the css3 just position you divs.

```
<div class="maincontainer">
 <div class="mainright">
 mainleft
 </div>
 <div class="mainleft">
 mainright
 </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
 <div class="footer-end">
 footer
 </div>
 </footer>
```

You have to switch position of div as shown in code and the apply the CSS

```
    .mainright{
    float:right;
width:70%;
    }
    .mainleft{
    float:right;
width:30%;
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.mainright{
    float:none;
width:100%;
    }
    .mainleft{
    float:none;
width:100%;
    }
}
```